# Include PHP File In Non-PHP or HTML File

Tags: php, apache, include, websmart

I am developing a web site on our iSeries server using [Websmart](http://www.bcdsoftware.com/iseries400solutions/websmart/), which generates RPG code that creates pages that are .pgm rather than .php or .html (eg: www.mydomain/index.pgm).

Websmart has a command that enables you to include files when a web page is generated, so that I can include a standard HTML/PHP header and footer, but we actually have a PHP header that has another PHP file included within it, and this just appears in the page source unprocessed.

I know you can add the following to Htdocs in Apache:

```
"AddType application/x-httpd-php .html"
```

but I wondered if this would also work for .pgm

```
"AddType application/x-httpd-php .pgm"
```

or whether Apache still recognizes HTML as a specific type of file when you do this.

Any ideas?  I can't think of another way to do this, and the PHP file that is included is right in the middle of the included Header.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Have you tried changing the htaccess file? It should work fine.

Comment: You can embed PHP code in a *.jpg file if you like. The PHP interpreter doesn't have any hard-coded extension.

Comment: I bit the bullet and tried it, but it didn't work.  These are the lines I have in the .htaccess, the last line is the one I added.

`Options +Includes
AddType text/html .html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .html .shtml .pgm
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html .shtml .pgm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .pgm`

I tried commenting out the other lines, but it made no difference.  The php include still shows in the page source as a red line (comment in FF).

Comment: A nasty red lightbulb just came on...   

My program generates the page source for the browser, but by the time it's output to the browser, any PHP code will be ignored surely, since the browser is on the client machine not the server.

Not sure about the point at which the PHP code is executed vs sent to the browser.

If I am right, maybe it would be possible to include the file contents using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe calling the PHP page using javascript (ajax) from the pgm file, it should work...

You can even call a PHP page passing to it some parameters and what you get you can say to the pgm page to write it entirely on the page (that's what pgm does, it creates at every click a new output page).

This is the ajax code to call a php page (you need jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

The you can use document.write() to output the entire string to the page instead of what generated by pgm.

Comment: Thanks Alberto. We got around this by ensuring the included page headers (.php) do not contain any PHP code (named .php not .html just for site consistency).